# Trouble building Open source software (ZeroMQ): autogen.sh

Tags: bash, sh

I'm trying to learn to build and poke around open source software. However, I've always had trouble trying to get anything to build. So, I figure now's as good a time as any to ask.

I downloaded the repo linked on this site: [OpenHub link to ZeroMQ](https://www.openhub.net/p/zeromq).

I am having trouble running the `autogen.sh` script in Ubuntu. The Install file says all I must do is run this script. However, I get the following error:

```
libzmq$ ./autogen.sh 
bash: ./autogen.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I have made the script executable, so I don't know what's wrong. The file is obviously there, and the first line indicates that it is a Bash script. Has anyone had this kind of issue before?

Comment: It looks like you have `\r\n` line endings in the `autogen.sh` file. Run `dos2unix` on it. Where did you get it from anyway?

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the input. How can you tell?

Here's the direct link to the repo: [ZeroMQ repo](git://github.com/zeromq/libzmq.git)

Comment: The `^M` in `/bin/sh^M`. Did you get it via Git? Have you configured line ending handling in Git somehow? BTW, it's a *shell script*, not a Bash script.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's a good thing to remember.

Also, forgive my incorrect usage of the terminology, but why is calling it a "bash script" incorrect?

Comment: Because the shebang is `#!/bin/sh`, so it has nothing to do with Bash. A Bash script would typically have `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Ah, sh vs. bash? Thanks. I shouldn't gloss over details like that. Especially as an aspiring programmer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75353/discussion-between-newbie-and-biffen).